# How to use COUNT and GROUP BY for more than one table?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

There are two tables in my schema - Houses and Cities. How would I determine the number of houses in each city using COUNT and GROUP BY?

```
Houses:
CityID
HouseNumber
StreetName

Cities:
CityID
CityName
Population
```

Please note: Houses.CityID is a foreign key to Cities.CityID. Thanks

Expected output:

```
City         Number of houses
London       50000000
NYC          30000000
Tokyo        40000000



SELECT CityName, count(*) as City
FROM Cities
GROUP BY CityName
```

Comment: Look at `JOIN` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I'm sorry but how will you join the two tables when there is no link? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Using `JOIN` to combine the two tables through City/CityName. You also need to `GROUP BY` this column.

```
SELECT t2.CityName, count(t1.*) 
FROM Houses t1 
JOIN Cities t2 
   ON t1.CityID = t2.CityID
GROUP BY t1.City
```

I used table name aliasing `t1` and `t2` to make the example obvious.

Comment: Hi kixorz, I'm confused about t1 and t2.

Comment: t1 and t2 are aliases/names he has created for accessing the individual tables (It's just easier than typing the full table name when extracting from them. The alternative would be Cities.CityName and count(Houses.*))

Comment: In this example you should note that if you have a cityName that doesn't exist in the cities table; the count of houses would be impacted.  Additionally if the database is case sensitive, then the counts could be impacted as well.

Answer (score 0):

With PK & foreign keys we know that in cities the CityID must be unique
we know in houses that CityID is a 1-M with cities.  and that any CityID in houses must exist in City. thus we don't need to worry about spelling mistakes, different casing etc.

So we select the name and count the houses via a join.  We add C.CityID to the group by as cityName may not be unique and we woudln't want two Springfield's to be merged.; thus we need to group by the CityID.

```
SELECT c.CityName, count(H.*)  as Number_of_Houses
FROM Cities C
INNER JOIN Houses H 
 on C.CityID = H.CityID
GROUP BY C.CityID, C.CityName
```

Comment: Hi @xQbert. I updated the question such that the two tables are now linked with a foreign key. Could you please help me out on this one, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Select Cities.CityName, count(Houses.*)
 From Houses inner join Cities on Cities.CityName=Houses.City
 group by Houses.City`

Answer (score 0):

```
select cities.cityName, count(houseNumber) as NumberofHouses
from Houses inner join cities on (houses.city = cities.cityName)
group by cityname;
```